# django-environ can't read docker container variables

Tags: python, django, docker, django-environ

I'm using Docker containers with Django. In my container I'm using environment variables via `.env` file

```
container_name:
    env_file: .env
```

I have echoe'd `SECRET_KEY` after the container is up and it shows the correct value set in `.env` file.

The problem is in my settings. When I do the following...

```
import environ

env = environ.Env()

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY', default='some_other_value')
```

... I was expecting "try to read 'SECRET_KEY' from the OS, but if you can't find it set it to 'some_other_value'. It turns out it isn't, having the following output:

```
get 'SECRET_KEY' casted as 'None' with default '<NoValue>'
```

On the other hand, if I do `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')` it gets the correct value.

What am I doing wrong with `django-environ` package?

Comment: Why don't you just use `os` instead of `environ` ? I've had the same problem just two days ago and I've decided to use `os`. No problems anymore.

Comment: I'm about to do the same, since you've had the same problem and have moved on :)

Comment: Hello, did you figure out how to solve it?